# C++ node to change dynamic reconfigure parameters

Tags: navigation, move-base, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using the turtlebot navigation move_base packages for my work and I would like to know if it's possible to change the planner parameters through a CPP API such as the max, min velocity and acceleration on the fly. I know move_base uses the dynamic reconfigure server, how can those parameters be accessed through a cpp program, for instance?

Thanks,
Sai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88356/c++-node-to-change-dynamic-reconfigure-parameters/) by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2013-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This question](http://answers.ros.org/question/12276/is-there-a-c-api-for-a-dynamic-reconfigure-client/) has several helpful answers, including a working example for modifying dynamic reconfigure parameters from a roscpp node.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2013-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on 2013-10-08**:
That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [this tutorial from 2010](http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingDynparamToChangeHokuyoLaserParameters#Using_dynparam_from_C.2B-.2B-_code), it's not yet implemented. I didn't see any cpp on the git repository, either. : (

The current suggestion on the tutorial is to use `system` command as a workaround.

---

Originally posted by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) with karma: 3562 on 2013-10-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-10-08**:
Feel free to complain here: https://github.com/ros/dynamic_reconfigure/issues/4

**Comment by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on 2013-10-08**:
That pretty much was what I would've resorted to, but Thomas D's link had a roscpp implementation that worked. Thanks.